# Error message when I run import glow in Python

Tags: python, glow

I just installed Python's library `glow.py` through poetry but, when I run `import glow` I receive the following error message:

```
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/mnt/0A2AAC152AABFBB7/side_projects/Genomics/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/glow/__init__.py", line 30, in <module>
    from .wgr import *  # For backwards compatibility. Avoid showing this import in docs.
  File "/mnt/0A2AAC152AABFBB7/side_projects/Genomics/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/glow/wgr/__init__.py", line 15, in <module>
    from glow.wgr.ridge_reduction import *
  File "/mnt/0A2AAC152AABFBB7/side_projects/Genomics/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/glow/wgr/ridge_reduction.py", line 15, in <module>
    from .ridge_udfs import *
  File "/mnt/0A2AAC152AABFBB7/side_projects/Genomics/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/glow/wgr/ridge_udfs.py", line 15, in <module>
    from glow.wgr.model_functions import *
  File "/mnt/0A2AAC152AABFBB7/side_projects/Genomics/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/glow/wgr/model_functions.py", line 25, in <module>
    from nptyping import Float, Int, NDArray
  File "/mnt/0A2AAC152AABFBB7/side_projects/Genomics/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/nptyping/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from nptyping.functions._get_type import get_type
  File "/mnt/0A2AAC152AABFBB7/side_projects/Genomics/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/nptyping/functions/_get_type.py", line 23, in <module>
    from nptyping.types._unicode import Unicode
  File "/mnt/0A2AAC152AABFBB7/side_projects/Genomics/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/nptyping/types/_unicode.py", line 30, in <module>
    class Unicode(NPType, numpy.unicode, metaclass=_UnicodeMeta):
  File "/mnt/0A2AAC152AABFBB7/side_projects/Genomics/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/numpy/__init__.py", line 328, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError("module {!r} has no attribute "
AttributeError: module 'numpy' has no attribute 'unicode'. Did you mean: 'unicode_'?
```

I do not understand quite well what it does mean or how to solve it.

I have found no information regarding this anywhere.

Comment: your error is _AttributeError: module 'numpy' has no attribute 'unicode'. Did you mean: 'unicode_'?_ so it has nothing to do with glow directly but with nptyping which is imported by it and calls the line `class Unicode(NPType, numpy.unicode, metaclass=_UnicodeMeta):` with the problematic statement **numpy.unicode** which should be **numpy.unicode_**

Comment: The problem is that `glow.py` uses `npytyping` 1.3.0 but in the latest version there is no problem with `numpy.unicode_`

Comment: See [Building and Testing](https://github.com/projectglow/glow#building-and-testing). Glow.py is not catching up upstream changes. As you can see in the [environment.yml](https://github.com/projectglow/glow/blob/master/python/environment.yml), you need to install Numpy 1.20.1 for example.